# codeigniter helper not load in linux, working fine in my windows local host

Tags: php, codeigniter

loading helper in my localhost windows work fine but when i move my code in linux live server it show me error 
Unable to load the requested file: helpers/loginfunction_helper.php

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('login_mdl/Login_model', 'fun');
    $this->load->helper('loginFunction');
    sec_session_start();
    if (login_check($this->fun) == true) {
        redirect(base_url('').'Pages/view/deshboard');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `loginfunction` instead of `loginFunction`

Comment: Linux filenames are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

`Case-sensitive` issue with file on linux server

Replace it :

```
$this->load->helper('loginFunction');
```

with

```
$this->load->helper('loginfunction');
```

*Whole `index` method should be like this :*

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('login_mdl/Login_model', 'fun');
    $this->load->helper('loginfunction');
    sec_session_start();
    if (login_check($this->fun) == true) {
        redirect(base_url('Pages/view/deshboard'));
    } else {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: have you checked my answer is it helpful for you?